# Swagger Pattern not working with Swagger UI

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, swagger-editor

I am making an API with swagger and am trying to update the YAML to add regex pattern requirements to the parameters. Currently I am trying the following:

```
# getCPIStatesForCountry endpoint
  /getCPIStatesForCountry:
    # This is a HTTP operation
    get:
      # Describe this verb here. Note: you can use markdown
      description: |
        Returns a list of states for a given country
      produces:
      - application/json
      # This is array of GET operation parameters:
      parameters:
        -
          name: country_code
          in: query
          description: Code of desired country
          required: true
          type: string
          pattern: "^[a-zA-Z]+$"
```

The Swagger UI, however, is letting me enter anything as valid input.  Why is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parameter validation against `pattern` is supported in Swagger UI 3.4.3 and later.